# How to define typedef for member of a union

Tags: c++, typedef

For convenience I want to use a typedef for the inner GVResponseEvent inside this GVEvent union.

My attempt gives me compilation errors:

```
warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of '_GVEvent' when no variable is declared
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
error C2059: syntax error : '.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef struct {
int                 type ;
int                 status ;
} GVResponseEvent ;

typedef union _GVEvent {
   int                         type ;
   GVResponseEvent          gvresponseevent;
} GVEvent ;


typedef GVEvent.GVResponseEvent resp_evt;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   resp_evt.status = 9; *** not working

   GVEvent myevt;
   myevt.type = 2;
   myevt.gvresponseevent.status = 9;
   myevt.gvresponseevent.type = 8;

   int gvresptype = myevt.gvresponseevent.type;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: gvresposeevent is a variable, not a type. Please consider inserting an example on how you intend to use resp_evt

Comment: The inner `GVResponseEvent` member inside this `GVEvent` union has the type `GVResponseEvent`, which you have already `typedef`-ed.

Comment: `GVEvent.GVResponseEvent` doesn't make sense to the compiler: Both denote types, so why should they nest. `resp_evt.status = 9` doesn't make much sense either, as `resp_evt` would be a type, not a variable.

Comment: What you want to do does not make sense. It is the same as making a typedef of struct or class member. As dasblinkenlight said, the member already has its type.

Answer (score 0):

`GVResponseEvent` is a type on its own. It's *not* defined in `union _GVEvent`.

You can `typedef` it like this:

```
typedef GVResponseEvent resp_evt;
```

This is how it would have looked like if it *was* defined in the union:

```
typedef union _GVEvent {
   int                         type ;
   typedef struct whatever{ int x; } GVResponseEvent;
   GVResponseEvent          gvresponseevent;
} GVEvent ;
```

And this is how you would have `typedef`ed it, if this was the case:

```
typedef GVEvent::GVResponseEvent resp_evt;
```

Note the `::`.

---

On another subject, you can access data in variables not types.

If you have

```
typedef whatever your_custom_type;
```

It doesn't make sense to write `your_custom_type.field` in the same way that it doesn't make sense to write `int += 10;`

Since you are making `resp_evt` a type (by using `typedef`), `resp_evt.status` won't make sense. As [enobayram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520737/912144) mentions, maybe you are looking for a pointer/reference?

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code

```
typedef GVEvent.GVResponseEvent resp_evt;
```

is syntactically wrong. The field the struct cannot be used as source type. The syntax of typedef is:

`typedef old_type new_type;`

The new type is expected to have modifiers like `*`, `[25]`, `(int x, long y)`, etc.

And what is its purpose? You already have type `GVResponseEvent`. Just use it.

Answer (score 0):

> typedef GVEvent.GVResponseEvent

GVResponseEvent is not a type defined in the scope of GVEvent. Your code therefore makes no sense to the compiler, or to me either.